# Convert a semicolon delimited csv to xlsx format from command line

Tags: excel, vbscript, csv

I want to generate an Excel file from a CSV file which I pass as an argument to VBScript. I adapted a script to get this code:

```
Dim file, WB
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    For Each file In WScript.Arguments
        Set WB = xl.Workbooks.Open(file,0,True,6, ,,,,";")
        WB.SaveAs Replace(LCase(WB.FullName), ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
        WB.Close False
    Next
```

I used the parameters `Workbooks.Open(file, 0, True, 4)` after reading the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx). `4`is for "semicolon delimited text".

The script generates the .xlsx file but doesn't consider semicolon as a delimiter but comma instead.

**Sample input :**

```
Ticket N°;CustLName;Destination;Stopover;StartTime
TVA5854656;Coleman;Fredericton;Montreal;20170110 08:25:00
TVA5854695;Nixon;Brandon;Montreal,Fredericton,Moncton;20170110 08:25:00
TVA5854752;Simard;Halifax;Montreal,Fredericton;20170111 08:25:00
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Ticket N°;CustLName;Destination;Stopover;StartTime      
TVA5854656;Coleman;Fredericton;Montreal;20170110 08:25:00       
TVA5854695;Nixon;Brandon;Montreal   Fredericton Moncton;20170110 08:25:00
TVA5854752;Simard;Halifax;Montreal  Fredericton;20170111 08:25:00
```

Comment: Works for me. Please remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get an error. Also, please show a representative sample of your input file.

Comment: **semicolon2excel.vbs(6, 9) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Workbooks'**

Comment: Ah, yes, there's a dot missing before `Workbooks`: `Set WB = .Workbooks.Open(...)`.

Comment: I changed the code a bit but cannot get it too work when the file has an extension of CSV.  If I give it a TXT extension it works fine.  Regardless of using Open or OpenText method.  It is almost like Excel automatically treats a file with a CSV extension as a comma delimited file regardless of the option you feed it to open the file.

Comment: @Squashman: Right. `*.csv` is not simply "Text" for `Excel`. The import of `*.csv` files using `Workbooks.Open` works only with CSVs in the locale format (delimiter, text-delimiter) the Excel is using. So if the locale settings have semicolon as the list delimiter, then it will work with semicolon delimited CSVs, else not.

Comment: @AxelRichter, not understanding why it will not work with the OpenText method then.  That should tell Excel you are opening a text file regardless of the file extension. `oXL.Workbooks.Opentext file, , , 1, , false, false, True, false, false, false`

Comment: So the very last parameter for the OpenText method is for local regional settings. **Specify True if regional settings of the machine should be used for separators, numbers and data formatting.** I set it to false and it still does not work unless the file extension is NOT csv. `oXL.Workbooks.Opentext file, , , 1, , false, false, True, false, false, false, , , , , , , false`

Comment: @Squashman: All those parameters are working for text only but not for CSV. For CSV you have to set `Local:=True` and then it always uses the delimiter from locale settings.

Comment: I updated the question after reading the comments.

Comment: @AxelRichter : Do you mean i have to give up and write a Java program and just forget the vbscript solution?

Comment: I think the possibilities using VBScript are clear: Either use `.Open` or `.OpenText` after renaming the files from `*.csv` to `*.txt` (maybe rename them back later) or you don't use `.Open` or `.OpenText` but read the `*.csv` files as plain text files using VBScript (using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` or `ADODB.Stream`) line by line and split the lines on `;` to get the field contents.

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution is to do a rename of the file at the beginning of the script and then rename it after it is done processing.  I did see some vbscript code that does a text to columns to split the file on the semi colon but that seems more complicated then just renaming the input file and then renaming it back to the original.  One other final option is to have the first line of your csv file be `sep = ;`.  That will force Excel to use the semicolon as the delimiter.